# Dynamically generate a string that references the variable name

Tags: javascript

I'm using [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) to find all references to "old/site/ and replace with File_Path.

File_Path is a variable that is declared globaly.

Here's is my config

```
let FILE_PATH;

const replace = require('replace-in-file');

const options = {

    // file to update
    files: './output.js',

    // replacement to make (string or regex) 
    from: "old/site/",
    to: "FILE_PATH+",
};

// asynchronous replacement with promises:
replace(options)
    .then(changedFiles => {
        console.log('Modified files:', changedFiles.join(', '));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    });
```

So as you can see 'to' is set to "FILE_PATH+" which gives the result

```
"FILE_PATH+childurl"
```

The result I am looking for though is

```
FILE_PATH+"childurl
```

How do I pass a ref of the variable and not the var name as a string?

**EDIT**

I have a script called output.js
I have a update_script.js

**output.js** contains this line of code

```
e.exports=n.p+"old/site/logo.svg"
```

**update_script.js** is running the code above which finds all references to "old/site/" and replaces it with "FILE_PATH+" so the new path looks like

**What I want**

```
e.exports=n.p+FILE_PATH+"/logo.svg"
```

So my question is how do I pass FILE_PATH without passing it as a string. Right now when I pass "FILE_PATH+" the url get update to

**What I get**

```
e.exports=n.p+"+FILE_PATH+/logo.svg"
```

Comment: Change `to: "FILE_PATH+"` to  `to: FILE_PATH + "+"`?

Comment: this will add the value of FILE_PATH to the string. I want to reference the variable itself e.g "www."+FILE_PATH+"childurl.com"

Comment: Ah, I see. You can get the matched part by using a callback function. See my answer.

Comment: The last part of the url should be a string

Comment: So what is the value of `FILE_PATH`? Can you give an example of its value and what effect that has on the replacement?

Comment: the value of FILE_PATH doesnt get generated until a seperate build task is ran after the script is executed above. So passing the value of FILE_PATH wont work at this stage because it is undefined. So I want to reference FILE_PATH as a string in to: but use it like +FILE_PATH+ on the other side. 

I slowing starting to realise that is probably isn't possible.

Comment: `e.export` is a string. Once it has received a value, it does not dynamically change when `FILE_PATH` changes. If you want that, then `e.export` should not be a string, but a *function* returning a string, which you would need to call whenever `FILE_PATH` is set.

Comment: Is `global.js` the same thing as `output.js`?

Comment: Sorry yes i'm using random file names here. I'll update the question.

Comment: I think it is important to see *when* you set `FILE_PATH`, and when you perform the replacement. Can you provide a single piece of code that shows the sequence of events/actions? For instance, I don't get what the variable `FILE_PATH` has anything to do with your question if you really want a *literal* occurrence of the word FILE_PATH in your output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the callback value for `to`. Its argument will be the matched string:

```
const options = {
  files: './pgReactBuild/static/js/main.80e5f778.chunk.js',
  from: "old/site/",
  to: (childurl) => FILE_PATH + childurl,
};
```

Comment: This doesnt work. It still passes the value of FILE_PATH and not "FILE_PATH"

Comment: I don't understand. I thought you said you wanted a ref to the variable, not the literal string. But now you say you want "FILE_PATH", which is a string literal?

Comment: No, I don't understand. It seems from the question that "FILE_PATH" is what you ***don't*** want. But here you say that is what you ***do*** want. I am confused.